# Need to find dependent stored procedure list in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

There is a table in redshift, which is causing a problem to complete a run as it has huge data set. So I need to replace the table with another table. This table is present in few stored procedure code. But here is a challenge. There are around 300+ stored procedure in the database. So, anyone please help me to write with a query, like what are list of procedures that using the particular table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the catalog `pg_proc` like this to find out if `<particular table>` is used in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT n.nspname as schema_name,
u.usename as sp_owner,
p.proname as stored_procedure_name,
p.prosrc as procedure_source
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON pronamespace = n.oid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user u on u.usesysid = p.proowner
where prosrc like '%<particular table>%';
```

Or you could use [PG_PROC_INFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_PROC_INFO.html), a Redshift system view built on the PostgreSQL catalog table `PG_PROC` and the internal catalog table `PG_PROC_EXTENDED`.